# Cannot format list of algorithms using titletoc with algorithms package

Tags: algorithms, titletoc

I am not sure what I am doing wrong, but I cannot get the titletoc formatting to work on my list of algorithms. I am using algorithm and algpseudocode, not algorithm2e. In the following, just as an example, I am trying to have the listings formatted using \sffamily\Large, just so that the difference is obvious. Thanks in advance for any pointers.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{xcolor} 
\usepackage[chapter]{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{titletoc} 
\usepackage{lipsum}

% List of Algorithms Formatting
\titlecontents{algorithm}[0em]
  {\addvspace{5pt}\sffamily\Large}
  {\thecontentslabel\hspace*{1em}}
  {}
  {\ \titlerule*[.5pc]{.}\;\thecontentspage}
  []

\begin{document}

\listofalgorithms

\chapter{Introduction}

\lipsum[1]

\section{Algorithm 1}

\lipsum[2]

\begin{algorithm}[H]
  some text here
  \caption{My Nifty Algorithm}
\end{algorithm}

\section{Algorithm 2}

\lipsum[2]

\begin{algorithm}[H]
  some text here
  \caption{My Niftier Algorithm}
\end{algorithm}

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```